# in ruby what happens if I define a function named new in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What if a make a class `Foo` and define a function called `initialize` *and* a function called `new`?

Later on, if I code `foo = Foo.new`, which function will be running? Since the `initialize` function is supposed to be called when declaring `new`.

EDIT:

for clarification:

```
class Foo
    def new
    end
end
```

that's the sort of thing I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4):

If you defined `new` on the class, it would call your function and override the typical `new` method which would create a new instance of the class. It's better if you don't override it at all, but you can still do it *and* get away with it in Ruby because Ruby's nice like that.

If you still want a new instance of the class after that, you can call `Foo.allocate` to get that. Then you can call `initialize` on that object manually to trigger any initialization events.

Answer (score 2):

The manually defined `new` function will not be called when doing `Foo.new` because the manually defined `new` function will be an *instance* function. `Foo.new` is calling a *class* function.

```
class Foo
    def new
        puts 'new!'
        123
    end

    def initialize
        puts 'initialize'
    end
end

c = Foo.new
puts c  #this will print "#<Confusion:0xb75b20f4>"
c.new   #this will print "new!"
```

EDIT:

If, however, I did this:

```
class Foo
    def Foo.new
    end
end
```

then we would run into problems as @Ryan pointed out.